# JSON NSBundle Error - Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: json, swift, swift2, nsbundle

I have problem with parsing JSON.

This is structure of JSON:

```
[{"id":33,"name":"5","sort":2},{"id":34,"name":"6","sort":3},{"id":35,"name":"7","sortOrder":4}]
```

And after running I have fatalError:

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)” with code "fatalError("error")"
```

Problem is with NSBundle. I suppose because I've added code:

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sections", ofType: "json"),
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) else {
            fatalError("error")
    }
    do {
        if let sections = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData,
            options: .MutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                // work with sections
                let addr = Address(dict: sections)
                print("sections")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

But there is no "sections". In fact link with JSON has no path - there are just objects (id, name, sort etc.). So how should I change guard let path = NSBundle to manage this problem?

Comment: Do you have in your app a file `sections.json`? If not, what are you doing with `NSBundle`?

Comment: No, JSON is taken from URL as string. So what instead of NSBundle should I use?

Comment: How do you get the string? Get it, and transform it into NSData (there is a method for it).

Comment: let urlAsString = "http://www.xxx.xxx"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let username = "xxx"
        let password = "xxx"

Comment: Just save that string then ! Don't call `NSBundle`.

Comment: Sorry for basic question - how to save it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108522/discussion-between-szekspir-and-larme).

Comment: There is no "sections" because your JSON is an **array of dictionaries**, not a dictionary. Change the type of your downcasting.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check your file in "DocumentDirectory and UserDomainMask"  for this purpose need to check if file available,

```
   let resourcePath = (bundle as! NSBundle).pathForResource("sections", ofType: "Json")
```

above code will find file in your directory if file is available there .

```
let resourcePath = self.bundle.pathForResource("sections", ofType: "Json");
```

P.S Please check your file is there in copyBundleResources.